# Why unsigned short int get promoted to unsigned int even when the sizes are same?

Tags: c

When we perform any operation on unsigned short int it gets promoted to unsigned int even on a machine in which both data types have same size. What is the purpose of such a promotion ? How does it help ? Isn't it just a change of name (since both have same size) ?

Comment: The types are still different from the perspective of the C type system, even if they consume the same number of bits in memory on your particular platform.

Comment: @Reuben can you please give an example on how does this help in any way. Do we need to worry about such a conversion ? Will it be a potential bug ever ?

Comment: There are extant platforms / machines / OSes on which `sizeof(unsigned short int) != sizeof(unsigned int)`

Comment: So can we say that such a conversion will never have any impact on a machine in which sizeof(unsigned short int) == sizeof(unsigned int)

Comment: What OS are you running on?  Is that the ***only*** OS you'll ever need to run on in the entire future of your program?

Comment: Its for embedded application. I dont forsee any change of OS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7947/discussion-between-bubble-and-reuben)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original mandate of the ANSI C committee was to codify existing practice, not create a new language.

And the C standard, in all its iterations through ANSI and ISO have taken backwards compatibility very seriously.

In other words, it's done that way because it's always been done that way :-)

The reason the promotion is done is because the standard is for *all* implementations, including those where the sizes are different.

But I'm not sure what you're complaining about. Promotion where the types are the same size is very unlikely to have a performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, because that's the way Dennis Ritchie decided it should be back in the early 1970s when he first set out the rules for C (or, at least, first set out the rules for C with support for `unsigned` integer types, but that was already because `short` was promoted to `int`).